# What should I do to link Python OpenCV and Three.js through WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, opencv, websocket, three.js

How to make augmented reality application with three.js and opencv. I found this article https://smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/simple-augmented-reality-with-opencv-a-three-js/
 and this is the code https://gist.github.com/martinsik/a3d6142b0392d77c13ab#file-circle_detection-py but what I cant understand that how to link opencv code and three.js to run this project.

Comment: Hello Usman, welcome to SO! Please edit your post to format it a bit, and create the hyperlink to your article.

Comment: Which article ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the link. Please review the question Pailhead.